# Intersection of commutative factorial domains: completely integrally closed and Krull domain

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A=\bigcap_{t\in T}D_t$ be an integral domain such that $D_t$ is a commutative factorial domain for every $t\in T$. It is quite natural to see that $A$ is a completely integrally closed domain. Moreover if we assume that $T$ is finite, $A$ is also a Krull domain.
My question is, do you know where I can find a reference for these two results? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not the book at hand, but I am very confident that you will find all you need in "Multiplicative Ideal Theory" by Robert Gilmer. This being said, I don't think you need references for the two results you mentioned because they can be derived very easily from the following well-known and easy facts: (1) A factorial domain (= UFD) is a Krull domain (2) A DVR is completely integrally closed (3) An intersection of completely integrally closed domains is completely integrally closed. (4) A finite intersection of Krull domains is a Krull domain.

Comment: For (2), you may check Exercise 9.4 of Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory" (the statement holds true more generally for integrally closed Noetherian domains). Assertions (3) and (4) are trivial. Assertion (1) can be shown directly by localizing a UFD at principal prime ideals.

Answer (score 3):

The two results you mentioned readily follow from well-known facts in multiplicative ideal theory. I provide **references** for those facts in the proofs below.

> **Claim 1.** Let $K$ be a field and let $\{D_t\}_{t \in T}$ be a family of unital subrings of $K$ where $T$ is some index set. If $D_t$ is a [factorial domain (a.k.a. UFD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) for every $t \in T$, then $A := \bigcap_{t \in T} D_t$ is [completely integrally closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain#Completely_integrally_closed_domains).

> *Proof.* A factorial domain is a [Krull domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_ring), see e.g., the first part of the proof of [Theorem 8.31, 1]. Krull domains are completely integrally closed because [discrete valuation rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring) are completely integrally closed (see e.g. [Theorem 8.12, 1] or simply [Exercise 9.4, 2]) and an intersection of completely integrally closed domains is completely integrally closed (this part is immediate). Therefore $A$ is completely integrally closed.

> **Claim 2.** Let $A$ be as in Claim 1. If $T$ is finite, then $A$ is a [Krull domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_ring).

> *Proof.* We already observed in the proof of Claim 2 that each factorial domain $D_t$ is a Krull domain. It follows immediately from the definition of a Krull domain that intersecting finitely many Krull domains results in a Krull domain.

---

[1] M. Larsen and P. McCarthy, ["Multiplicative Theory of Ideals"](https://promathmedia.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/multiplicative-theory-of-ideals.pdf), 1971.

[2] H. Matsumura, "Commutative Ring Theory", 1986.

Comment: I was looking for a direct reference,  since the two results are quite obvious and I supposed someone had proved them somewhere. Never mind, thank you very much!

Comment: I was afraid that no such results exist in the literature, precisely because they are immediate and/or they can be quickly derived from well-known ones. You may  nonetheless check Gilmer's book: it's an amazing resource. (Side note: "A UFD is completely integrally closed" has a simple and direct proof; possibly the one you had in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is Exercise 7 in Section 3.4 in my book, *Rings, Modules, and Closure Operations* (2020).  Note that, for the intersection to be a Krull domain, all you need is that the intersection be *locally finite*, that is, that every nonzero element of the intersection be a unit in $D_t$ for all but finitely many $t \in T$.

Also, the proof will depend on what your definition of a Krull domain is.  There are several (equivalent) ways of defining them.